# How to kill libreoffice from command line

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, process

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 64 bit. My LibreOffice suite (especially Writer) freezes.

How can I kill LibreOffice and Can I kill only the writer? (not the Calc,Impress,..)

I tried to search for the executable process at System Monitor and command line (`ps`) but didn't find it.

**EDIT**: I want something like this:

```
pkill -9 writer
```

I need some kind of *minified* command.

Comment: But why `-9`? It is better to use `-9` only when you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First search for open libreoffice files:

```
ps aux | grep libre
```

For example the output of mine is:

```
hadi  21426  0.1  0.0 205328  3468 ?        Sl   14:17   0:00 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash --writer
hadi  21445  9.8  0.7 1269272 179872 ?      Sl   14:17   0:01 /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin --writer --splash-pipe=6
```

then

```
sudo kill -9 ID
```

the ID is the second number for (soffice.bin) not for oosplash

so in my example:

```
sudo kill -9 21445
```

---

You need professional Ok:

```
ps aux | grep -i office | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9
```

hope this is professional in your evaluation!!

or more *minified* command

```
kill -9 `pgrep -lf soffice.bin | awk {'print $1'}`
```

or more *minified minified minified* command

```
pkill soffice.bin
```

---

EDIT:

All libreoffice open files take the same PID, for that you can't just kill writer and keep impess for example.

And to prove my point of view the recovery tool in office is unique for all files. What i mean if you close a writer in imporper way and then open an impress for example then impress will request you to recovery the writer file and it did so and this proves my answer

Comment: no when killing soffice it will kill all libreoffice programs when opened , try to open impress and writer and kill this process it will kill them both, it is a parent process

Comment: op needs just to kill writer , maybe he use to open calc and impress with writer :)

Comment: @nux YES that's someone who understands my need

Comment: You can't do it. All libreoffice open files take the same PID.

Comment: Open writer and impress and calc and then `ps aux|grep office` and you'll see that no entries for other than writer. Since all files inherit the same PID.

Comment: And to prove my point of view the recovery tool in office is unique for all files. What i mean if you close a writer in imporper way and then open an impress for example then impress will request you to recovery the writer file and it did so and this proves my answer

Comment: mmmm any official link would be helpfull. But that means your answer is wrong. Am I right ?

Comment: No my answer is not wrong. I didn't told you that you can just kill each type alone. For official link I'm seraching

Comment: Nothing impossible in linux , thats a word somebody told me

Comment: This is critical for logic people just try and test what i say before and you can believe in what i say :) That's the true. 
Badly libreoffice doesn't mention any officail information about that

Answer (score 9):

You should try:

```
killall soffice.bin
```

Answer (score 2):

use `ps -e` to list all processes running (not just those spawned by your current terminal). You can then search for the name you are looking for (Perhaps 'writer' or 'Libre'). If you know exactly the name you're looking for you could use `ps -e | grep writer` to give you the results for that process only.

You should see a number which is the process id (PID). To kill the process, enter `kill x` where `x` is the PID of the process. You should get a message saying something along the lines of `killed 1 process`. If the process is still running, try `kill -KILL x` to force the program to quit.

Comment: it doesn't work my dear

Comment: Which bit didn't work?

Comment: `ps -e | grep writer` doesn't return anything

Comment: You'll have to just use `ps -e` and search through the names for the right process. `writer` was just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

### Using killall

I usually just get away with killing oosplash

```
killall oosplash
```

or soffice.bin

```
killall soffice.bin
```

oosplash shows up higher in the pstree -p.

### Using pstree

This function can be placed in your .bashrc file as a shortcut command. It searches the output of `pstree -p` for the PID of your search term.

```
piddler(){
    searchTerm=$1
    echo "Searching for ${searchTerm} processes:" 
    pstree -p | grep -oE "([a-zA-Z.-])*${searchTerm}([a-zA-Z.-])*\([0-9]{3,7}\)" | grep -oE "[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z.-])*\([0-9]{3,7}\)"
}
```

You can use it to find a system process like this:

```
piddler office
```

It'll output something like this:

```
Searching for office processes:
soffice.bin(8707)
```

Then you can kill the process with:

```
kill -9 8707
```

Answer (score 0):

## In a `makefile`

In a `makefile`, error messages can be avoided with either:

```
-killall -q oosplash
```

or

```
-@killall oosplash
```

The characters in front of the `killall` command do the trick.

However, even more gracefully would be:

```
-@wmctrl -c LibreOffice
```

or, even safer:

```
-@wmctrl -c filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, when I opened second document in LO Writer. I was not able to close not only LO, but anything, even UBUNTU. A simple, not ideal solution was:

- Open Terninal
- shutdown

When I opened the UBUNTU and LO again, it asked me, if  I want to save the last document before the crash. My answer was (to be careful) no.
Then I had no problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Usung killall -e

As Thomas Nyman said in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91540/382418

> killall somewhat safer to use compared to pkill

Therefore i use: `killall -e soffice.bin` using (kUbuntu 20.4)

> The -e, --exact option can be specified to also require exact matches for names longer than 15 characters.